# Object oriented programming: IS-A vs HAS-A relationships?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am learning about object oriented programming from

> Problem solving with Algorithms and Data structures

book using the online version available on interactive python website. Link is mentioned below.

[Object Oriented Programming](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html)

I have trouble understanding the `Connector` class that is mentioned in the above link. What exactly is the difference between IS-A and HAS-A relationship?

```
class Connector:

    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate

        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate
```

The method `setNextPin` defined in `BinaryGate(LogicGate)` has an input of `source`. But when it is being accessed in `Connector` class, we are not giving a second argument. So how can it be implemented even without giving all the arguments.

Also, how can the `setNextPin` method in `Connector` class understand that it can access the method defined for it in `BinaryGate` class?

I tried had to figure it out but I couldn't. Can someone help me understand this.

Comment: To answer your first sub-question: The call to `tgate.setNextPin(self)` does result in the method receiving two arguments named `self` and `source` in its declaration. Whenever an object method is called, it first argument passed is always the object—this is `tgate` in the caller—plus any additional arguments listed in parentheses following the method name. In this case it's the `Connector` instance which is called `self` on the caller side, but referred to as `source` in the callee's code. The different names on the two sides is likely the cause of your confusion on that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot @martineau. I read about this kind of implementation before in OOP. But I couldn't figure it out until you mentioned about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two things here: implied function parameters and duck typing.

Firstly, the syntax `tgate.setNextPin(self)` calls the function `setNextPin(tgate, self)`.  The first parameter is the object for which the method is being called (usually named self).  You are getting confused because we are passing `self` as the *second* parameter to the function `setNextPin` but the first parameter of that function is also called `self`.  This is a scoping issue, those two `self`s refer to different parameters (depending on which function you are in).

Secondly, there is duck typing.  How does the function know it can access the method in the `BinaryGate` class? It doesn't know that at all!  All the function knows is that it expects `tgate` to be of a type that has a method `setNextPin`.  It doesn't matter if this is a `BinaryGate` or any other object.  If the object passed doesn't have this method to call then Python will fail at run time as it will be unable to find the function `setNextPin` to call.

Comment: Thanks @dave. I will read more about duck typing. It makes lot of sense when you explained that it doesn't matter whether it is a `BinaryGate` or any other object as long as  `tgate` class has `setNextPin` method